# Populate calendar table using loops

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Given the following code snippet, I need to create this

[image]

I am not allowed to edit the existing code, and I am supposed to accomplish this by adding a nested loop.

```
var daysOfWeek = newArray("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday");
daysOfWeek.push("Saturday");
daysOfWeek.unshift("Sunday");
document.write("<table border=1><tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++){
    document.write("<th>"+daysOfWeek[i]+"</th>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
```

I understand how to create a table using a for loop when the rows are created first. However, I cannot get it to work when the th's are created first.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you elaborate this `However, I cannot get it to work when the th's are created first`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who teaches you to use `document.write` instead of all the other more secure ways to append a HTML string or even HTMLElements to document?

Comment: You mentioned you are not allowed to edit the existing code and you couldn't get it to work. Could you also add what you tried?

Comment: Also,  `newArray()` sbould be `new Array()`, no, actually just `[]`;

Comment: I have tried adding nested loops for loops which add <td> elements from 1-30, but when I do the whole table disappears.  I completely understand how loops work, I think it is the way I am adding rows and table data that is messing things up.  @RokoC.Buljan this is a portion of lab given by my professor.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I mean I can create a table similar to this when the initial for loop creates 7 rows as opposed to 7 table headings.  I do not know how to nest a loop that will accomplish this task without changing the initial for loop

Answer (score 4):

```js
// Tell to prof:
// Instead of new Array() I'll use the faster []
var daysOfWeek = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"];

daysOfWeek.push("Saturday");
daysOfWeek.unshift("Sunday");

// Tell to prof:
// Instead of form of eval "document.write" I'll use String concatenation:
var table = "<table border=1><tr>";
for (var i=0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++){
    table += "<th>"+daysOfWeek[i]+"</th>";
    // NOTE:
    // if inside this loop we're creating the 7 <th>s headings,
    // than we cannot assert another inner loop here
    // to create any other part of the calendar,
    // cause we're inside the scope of the table headings.
    // Here we're still populating the first <tr> row!!
}
table += "</tr>"; // <<< just here we're finally done with the Days headings


// OK, now the homework: add to table rows / and 30 cells 
var days = 30; // How many days we need?
var appendEmptyDays = 7 - (days+7) % 7; // How many empty cells we miss?

table += "<tr>";

// CREATE DAYS (and WEEKS)
for(var i=1; i<=days; i++){
  table += "<td>"+ i +"</td>";
  if(i%7===0) table += "</tr><tr>"; // Add a new week row?
}

// APPEND EMPTY CELLS
for(var i=0; i<appendEmptyDays; i++){
  table += "<td></td>";
}

table += "</tr></table>";

// Done my string concatenation, I'll now use innerHTML
document.body.innerHTML = table;
```

This cannot be used in any real environment website or app.
The code above doesn't takes into account that `1st` can end up being i.e: `Wednesday`...

You professor (hopefully he's reading this) should teach you how to create **interesting and useful stuff**, i.e: User-tables by looping data structures like i.e: *"2D"* Arrays, Object literals or JSON data, and not to waste time creating broken calendars.

Comment: very good solution! although I was asked to nest a loop within the initial for loop to complete this solution. I dont even know if there is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: That is my fault!  I was trying to say that I could not edit the for loop. just add a loop within it.

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry NO, you cannot add another nested loop inside the first one, cause inside the first one you are creating TH elements.

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry If the assignment is exactly like you say, to add another `for` loop inside the existing `for` loop, that the assignment is wrong by design.

Comment: thats what I thought. I'm glad I'm not insane. thank you.

Comment: @lewisfurlan-lowry You're very welcome. I expanded my answer with comments, hopefully you'll be able to understand, since EN in not my primary language.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my solution may be of service; it approaches with a nested-solution as requested.  This problem was assigned by the lab section within [Chapter 6 of Fundamentals of Web Development by Randy Connolly & Ricardo Hoar](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Fundamentals-of-Web-Development/9780133407150.page).

```js
var daysOfWeek = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br>");

// daysOfWeek.push("Saturday");
// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br/>");

// daysOfWeek.unshift("Sunday");
// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br/>");

document.write("<table border=1><tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++){
  document.write("<th>"+daysOfWeek[i]+"</th>");
}

document.write("</tr>");
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++){
  if (i % 7 == 1) document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
  if (i % 7 == 7) document.write("</tr>");
}
```

I appreciate the alternative approach provided by @RokoC.Buljan and agree with him; this is just a bad assignment-question with poor instructions, creating a gaping-hole in the learning-curve.  Although there is little application for this solution in modern web development, it is respectable for the sake of exercise.

## Update

Here is a much cleaner refactor, eliminating the redundancy in my initial solution above by nesting a conditional **else-if** statement checking for divisibility (*returning 0 when i is divided by 7*) within the for-loop, effectively creating a new table-row by closing the row, when day-number of the week is divided by 7 and returns a remainder of 0; otherwise, or `else`, the loop continues to increment table-row-cells for the day-number of the week until limited by the integer-constraint (30) specified within the for-loop definition `i <= 30`.

```js
 var daysOfWeek = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br>");

// daysOfWeek.push("Saturday");
// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br/>");

// daysOfWeek.unshift("Sunday");
// document.write(daysOfWeek+"<br/>");

document.write("<table border=1><tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++){
document.write("<th>"+daysOfWeek[i]+"</th>");
}
document.write("</tr><tr>");
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  if(i % 7 == 0){
    document.write("<td>"+i+"</td></tr>");
  }
  else{
    document.write("<td>"+i+"</td>");
  } 
};
document.write("</tr></table>");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are there any solutions that create a calendar for a specific month of a specific year, say, for example, March 2020 so they get the days of the week right for the actual numbers?

Comment: Nope- just be careful with those loops! ;)

Comment: actually I just found one that I could modify to suit my purposes.  :)

Comment: @ColleenKitchen, Ok, try it and see what happens- please let me know!  Thanks!